# How scope is determined in Python

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Why does the first print statement in the second function throw an error that `x` is not defined?

```py
x = 5

def function_a():
    print(x)


def function_b():
    print(x)
    x = 7
    print(x)
```

Running the first function gives the following result.

```py
>>> function_a()
5
```

While running the second function throws an error.

```py
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will *infer* and use the variable from the inner scope whenever it sees the variable declared within the scope, *even if that variable is declared after usage*.

To demonstrate this, I created two scenarios.

---

### Variable declared inside the inner scope

A variable is inferred in the following order: local, nonlocal, and global. Since `x` is declared inside the inner scope, Python will infer and use the `x` in this scope even if it is declared after usage.

Note that Python cannot distinguish *modification* from *declaration*; what was meant to modify `x` from the global scope was interpreted to declare another variable `x` within that scope.

[image: Inferred Inner]

### No variables declared inside the inner scope

If no variables are declared within the inner scope, Python will switch the inferred scope to nonlocal, and then to global.

[image: Inferred Global]

### Explicitly switching scope

If you explicitly declared the scope of `x` beforehand, Python would not have to infer.

[image: Declared Global]

The following code will not throw an error because the scope it uses is explicitly the global scope instead of the inner one.

```py
x = 5

def scope():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 7
    print(x)
```

---

### Scopes

By choosing which scope to work with, you are not only *using* the variables within that specific scope but also *modifying* the variables. Therefore, you need extra caution when dealing with scopes.

Because Python cannot distinguish *variable declaration* from *variable modification*, my advice is that if you want to use a global variable, you should explicitly state it beforehand.

This also applies to nested scopes.

```py
x = 5

def outer():
    x = 7

    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        print(x)
        x = 3
        print(x)
    
    inner()
```

Running the outer function gives the following result.

```py
>>> outer()
7
3
```

Try changing the `nonlocal` keyword to `global` and see a different result; or remove the line completely to get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd method, you have written x = 7, which makes x a local variable for that method. But since, you are trying to access it on the print statement before the line "x = 7", it throws an error saying local variable x is accessed before assignment.

If you remove the line x = 7, it would work just fine.
You can try this

```
x = 5

def vs_code():
    print(x)

def vs_code1():
    print(x)
    y = 7
    print(y)
```

this will print
5
5
7

Now, since I am not declaring x inside 2nd method, now x is not local for 2nd method. If you declare it inside 2nd method, it will interpret that as a local variable. and you have to use it only after assignment.

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

python is special in variable scope

you can use dis module to see what happeded.

```py
def foo():
    print(x)
    print(y)
    x = ...
import dis
dis.dis(foo)
```

output

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP

  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (y)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 POP_TOP

  4          16 LOAD_CONST               1 (Ellipsis)
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

x is `LOAD_FAST`

y is `LOAD_GLOBAL`
before running, python thinks **x** is a local variable because you try to modify it (cannot modify global variable).

this will works fine

```py
def vs_code1():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 7
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is assigned a value inside a function, that variable name is considered local. Unless it is explicitly declared as global with the line:

```
global x
```

In the first print of the function the variable `x` is not defined in the local scope. That-s why throws an error.

So you have to add the line `global x` at the beggining of the function body for the variable `x` be considered global despite it is assigned in the function.