# local and global variables in python

Tags: python, local-variables

```
def callme():
    print(x)
    x=20
x=10
callme()
```

`x = 10` is assigned globally(line-4), `callme()` calls `def callme():` executes first, then comes `print(x)`, So it has to print `10`, because python doesn't knows that there exists a variable `x=20` in the 3rd line. But these lines prints error.

```
def callme():
    print(x)
x=10
callme()
```

But in this case, it prints `10`. because `x` is defined as `global` variable.

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: I recently explained it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601011/how-scope-is-determined-in-python).

Comment: If there is an assignment of a variable in a function, in this case `x`. Then any references to  that variable prior to the assignment will result in an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: "because python doesn't knows that there exists a variable x=20 in the 3rd line" Python can (and does) look at the entire source code before execution.

Comment: Actually Python do know that there is a local variable in your function. Python is reading your whole file before executing and therefore it saves some informations. That's why you are getting an error, because Python think you want to work locally and not globally. Take a look at the comment from @MartesBerkeley for more informations.