# How variable scope works in Python

Tags: python, function, scope

```
myarray = [1,20,30,44,5,57,8]

def maxProduct(array):
    maxprod = array[0]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(i + 1,len(array)):
            if array[i] * array[j] > maxprod:
                maxprod = array[i] * array[j]
                pairs = str(array[i]) + "," + str(array[j])
    
    print(pairs) # **Expected an error but got the output -> 44,57**

maxProduct(myarray)
```

The pairs variable is being printed outside the if block. How is it printing without error?

Comment: Scopes work as you expect, just `for` and `if` create no scopes.

Comment: Note that this would raise an error, if the `if`-block were never executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How scope is determined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601011/how-scope-is-determined-in-python)

Comment: Python has function-scope and module-scope